# Story Of naive Cats And Machiavellian Monkey

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are some cats with some breads. This given as an array of integers. Now as the story goes the cats are fool and beguiled by the Machiavellian Monkey. The monkey comes and says the bread is not distributed wisely and takes upon himself do do the job in the city of cats.

The City looks like a straight array.

Cat 1 | Cat 2 | Cat 3 |....there always is a place for a new Cat.

Now the monkey takes 1 Bread from Cat 1 and Cat 2 and gives 1 to Cat 3 and keeps the other 1 for himself.This was just one case of many.In similar order or fashion , He can also take From Cat 2 and Cat 3 and give it to Cat 4 (from 3 and 4 to 5 and so on).Note that he cant take from cats if they have 0 bread.Now monkey can take again from Cat 1 and Cat 2 and give it to Cat 3 if they still have more than 0 bread, This being a new case as monkey and cats have different bread combination.So the question is to generalize the number of cases that could exist and the Max number of breads monkey can have.

Example:

*Cat 1 (1 Bread)| Cat 2 (2 Breads) | Cat 3 (0 Bread) | Cat 4(3 Breads)....(.. means more cats can be added if required)*
[image]

The above tree shows the combination of that cases exist.

Explanation:

Case 1: 1 2 0 3 - Cats have breads just as they had and monkey didnt take any so he has 0 Bread.

Case 2: 0 1 1 3 - Monkey took 1 bread from cat 1 and 2 and gave it to cat 3. So he has 1 bread.

Case 3: 0 0 0 4 - from previous case he took From cat 2 and cat 3 and gave it to cat 4. So he now has 2 bread.

Case 4: 0 1 0 2 1 - From case 2, he took from cat 3 and cat 4 and gave it to cat 5. So he now again has 2 bread.

Case 5: 0 1 0 1 0 1 - From previous case, he took from cat 4 and cat 5 and gave it to cat 6. So he has 3 Bread which is the max he can get as there is no other possible case.

**I want the answer For Example [1 2 3 4]**

Comment: It looks like the monkey takes bread from cat $n$ and $n+1$ giving one to cat $n+2$ and keeping the other.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the brute force algorithm I've obtained the following result:

`(result_id) [number_of_breads_taken] result_representation (reference_to_identical_result)`

> (000) [00] 1234 
>   (001) [01] 0144 
>   (002) [02] 0035 
>   (003) [03] 00241 
>   (004) [04] 00132 
>   (005) [05] 00023 
>   (006) [06] 000121 
>   (007) [07] 000012 
>   (008) [08] 0000011 
>   **(009) [09] 00000001** 
>   (010) [07] 0001101 
>   (011) [08] 0000011 (8)
>   (012) [05] 001211 
>   (013) [06] 000121 (6)
>   (014) [06] 001102 
>   (015) [07] 000012 (7)
>   (016) [06] 0012001 
>   (017) [07] 0001101 (10)
>   (018) [04] 002301 
>   (019) [05] 001211 (12)
>   (020) [02] 01331 
>   (021) [03] 00241 (3)
>   (022) [03] 01222 
>   (023) [04] 00132 (4)
>   (024) [04] 01113 
>   (025) [05] 00023 (5)
>   **(026) [05] 01004** 
>   (027) [05] 011021 
>   (028) [06] 000121 (6)
>   (029) [06] 0110101 
>   (030) [07] 0001101 (10)
>   (031) [04] 012111 
>   (032) [05] 001211 (12)
>   (033) [05] 011021 (27)
>   (034) [05] 012002 
>   (035) [06] 001102 (14)
>   (036) [05] 0121001 
>   (037) [06] 0012001 (16)
>   (038) [06] 0110101 (29)
>   (039) [03] 013201 
>   (040) [04] 002301 (18)
>   (041) [04] 012111 (31)
>   (042) [01] 1125 
>   (043) [02] 0035 (2)
>   (044) [02] 1016 
>   (045) [03] 10051 
>   **(046) [04] 100401** 
>   (047) [02] 11141 
>   (048) [03] 00241 (3)
>   (049) [03] 10051 (45)
>   (050) [03] 11032 
>   (051) [04] 00132 (4)
>   (052) [04] 110211 
>   (053) [05] 001211 (12)
>   (054) [05] 110102 
>   (055) [06] 001102 (14)
>   (056) [05] 1102001 
>   (057) [06] 0012001 (16)
>   (058) [03] 111301 
>   (059) [04] 002301 (18)
>   **(060) [04] 100401** (46)
>   (061) [04] 110211 (52)
>   (062) [01] 12231 
>   (063) [02] 01331 (20)
>   (064) [02] 11141 (47)
>   (065) [02] 12122 
>   (066) [03] 01222 (22)
>   (067) [03] 11032 (50)
>   (068) [03] 12013 
>   (069) [04] 01113 (24)
>   (070) [04] 120021 
>   (071) [05] 011021 (27)
>   (072) [05] 1200101 
>   (073) [06] 0110101 (29)
>   (074) [03] 121111 
>   (075) [04] 012111 (31)
>   (076) [04] 110211 (52)
>   (077) [04] 120021 (70)
>   (078) [04] 121002 
>   (079) [05] 012002 (34)
>   (080) [05] 110102 (54)
>   (081) [04] 1211001 
>   (082) [05] 0121001 (36)
>   (083) [05] 1102001 (56)
>   (084) [05] 1200101 (72)
>   (085) [02] 122201 
>   (086) [03] 013201 (39)
>   (087) [03] 111301 (58)
>   (088) [03] 121111 (74)
>   44 different cases 
>   9 breads taken at most

Python script:

```
class Result:
    id = 0
    level = 0
    value = ""
    refId = -1

    def __init__(self):
        return

results = list()


def solve(result, resultats):
    val = result.value
    for i in xrange(0, val.__len__()-1):
        if val[i] != "0" and val[i+1] != "0":
            a = int(val[i])
            b = int(val[i+1])
            c = 0
            if (i+2) < val.__len__():
                c = int(val[i+2])
            newres = ""
            for k in xrange(0, max(i+2, val.__len__())):
                character = val[min(k, val.__len__())]
                if k == i:
                    character = str(a-1)
                if k == i+1:
                    character = str(b-1)
                if k == i+2:
                    character = str(c+1)
                newres += character
            if i+2 == val.__len__():
                newres += str(c+1)

            res = Result()
            res.value = newres
            res.id = resultats.__len__()
            res.level = result.level+1
            refid = -1
            for x in resultats:
                if x.value == res.value and x.refId == -1:
                    refid = x.id
            res.refId = refid

            resultats.append(res)
            if refid < 0:
                solve(res, resultats)
    return result


res = Result()
res.value = "1234"
results.append(res)

solve(res, results)

counter = 0
maxBreadsTaken = 0
for x in results:
    if x.refId < 0:
        counter += 1
    if maxBreadsTaken < x.level:
        maxBreadsTaken = x.level

    pream = "("+str(x.id).zfill(3)+") " + "[" + str(x.level).zfill(2)+"] "
    ref = " "
    if x.refId >= 0:
        ref += "("+str(x.refId)+")"
    print pream + x.value + ref + "<br>"

print str(counter) + " different cases <br>"
print str(maxBreadsTaken) + " breads taken at most <br>"
```

Comment: TY Jaroslaw Matlak. This will help a lot. Now the only thing left is to check if the answer can be generalized using combinatorics.